# How can I set Windows as the default OS in Grub?

Tags: boot

I'ḿ a new user of Ubuntu, but I need Windows for official purposes, so I have both systems on my pc.

Can some one tell me how to configure (I prefer graphical support. like BootAdministrator') grub to start with windows as the default OS instead Ubuntu?